# Connection without arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbBloc[0]{B1}{1}{E}
    \sbBloc[3]{B2}{2}{B1}
    \sbRelier{B1}{B2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Using `schemabloc`, is there a way to make connection without arrow?

Comment: Seems you can use `\sbStyleLien{-}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couci?

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{sbStyleLien}=[-,>=latex']
    \sbEntree{E}
    \sbBloc[0]{B1}{1}{E}
    \sbBloc[3]{B2}{2}{B1}
    \sbRelier{B1}{B2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]